# Sign an unsigned xcarchive (or ipa)

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, sign

I have to sign an unsigned `.xcarchive` or `.ipa` file (I have both, I can choose the best solution). This app contains an extension. I have both the provisioning profiles of the main app and the extension and I have the Distribution certificate installed in my keychain. Everything I tried failed, I used iOS App Signer, I tried doing things manually, I guess I'm missing something.
Do you have a solution?
Thanks.